# Can I inject dependencies on the fly in angular.js?

Tags: angularjs

I have the following service:

```
var module = angular.module('app', []);

module.service('service', function(dep){

});
```

And suppose that I need to instantiate it somewhere in my code, with a different dependency, than the default one.

```
    //service is injected with the default 'dep' dependency
module.controller('controller', function(service, $injector) {


   //I need to call the service with my custom dependency
   //but $injector does not help, because it only gives back
   //the already injected service object
   var injectedService = $injector.get('service')

   //So theoretically I would need something like this
   //but I did not find such a feature yet
   var customDep = {...}
   var serviceWithCustomDep = $injector.inject('service', [customDep]);
});
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: It sounds like you want to define a [provider](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers) that exposes methods for hot-swapping the configuration.

Comment: Yes, something like that. But I would like to do it with the use of the dependency injection (not calling methods directly on a provider), because I may have to do this with internal (pre-packaged angularjs) providers, and I can not modify them.

Answer (score 1):

In short: use `$injector.invoke` function to invoke a function with dependencies injected.

Define a factory (or service) that will return a function which you will invoke with the dependencies you desire.

```
module.factory('myFactory', function () {
    return function () {
        //do stuff here with dependencies injected
    };
});
```

Then in your controller for example:

```
module.controller('MyController', function (myFactory, $injector) {
    //define the dependencies you want, for example:
    myFactory.$inject = ['$http', '$location'];
    $injector.$invoke(myFactory);
});
```

This way you can change the dependencies with which you invoke the `myFactory` function as you please, you only need to modify the `$inject` property of the function.

Here's a link with more info: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di